# clojure map, what is %2 and %1

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am doing a clojure excersice and this is one question.

```
(true?  (__ :a {:a nil :b 2}))
```

the answer is :

```
 #(nil?(%2 %1 0))
```

But I could not get it.
What does ％2 ％1 0 do here?
Especially, what does that 0 do there?

can you explain it for me?
thanks

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  What is `__`? %2 and %1 are place holders for what gets iterated over in the `#()` function.  But I don't see what they would be holding the place of here.  Maybe you can offer some more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was mentioned earlier,
`#(nil? (%2 %1 0))` is a sugar for

`(fn [a-map a-key] (nil? (a-map a-key 0)))`

A few things to notice about this line:

1. hash maps in clojure support the function semantics, so using the map in place of function is identical to calling `get` function

`(a-map a-key default-value)` equals to `(get a-map a-key default-value)`

2. zero as a default key is added to distinguish the **abscence of key** from a **`nil` value of key**. For example:

`(get {:b 1} :a)` produces `nil` (as there is no `:a` key in the map)

`(get {:a nil :b 1} :a)` also produces `nil` (as `nil` is a value of `:a`)

while using the default value removes this uncertainty:

`(get {:b 1} :a 0)` => 0

`(get {:a nil :b 1} :a 0)` => nil

3. the map in the example has numeric values, so using zero as a default value can lead to even bigger mess (well, depending on the use case. Sometimes zero is exactly what you need here). It is common to use some value that can't be there, for example a keyword like `:not-found`

But in this case you would probably want to do the task this way:

```
(true? (#(contains? %2 %1) :a {:a nil :b 2}))
```

As they obviously want you to check if the key `:a` is present in a map

Comment: Not only hash maps, sorted maps support the same function semantics. See the [official documentation on IPersistentMap](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Maps%20%28IPersistentMap%29).

Answer (score 7):

The #() format is shorthand for defining anonymous functions.
For example: `#(+ %1 %2)` is the equivalent of `(fn [a,b] (+ a b))`

Here `%2` and `%1` represent the second and the first argument to the function respectively.

Comment: THanks, so in this line : #(nil?(%2 %1 0))  what does it mean? Why there is a 0 ?

Comment: `0` would be used as a default return value. For example when the map `%2` does not have a key matching `℅1` at all.